# Template in C++ to include only unique types in variant

Tags: c++, templates

I am already using a template to concatenate variant type but I want to only include the unique types.

```cpp
// ------> The template function
template <typename Type, typename... Args> struct concat;
template <typename... Args0, typename... Args1>
struct concat<std::variant<Args0...>, Args1...> {
  using T = std::variant<Args0..., Args1...>;
};
template <typename... Args0, typename... Args1, typename... Args2>
struct concat<std::variant<Args0...>, std::variant<Args1...>, Args2...> {
  using T = std::variant<Args0..., Args1..., Args2...>;
};

// -----> Usage
using A = std::variant<int, double>;

using B = concat<A, long>::T; // std::variant<int, double, long>
using C = concat<A, float>::T; // std::variant<int, double, float>
```

When I do

```cpp
using D = concat<B, C, std::string>::T;
```

Type of `D` is

```cpp
std::variant<int, double, long, int, double, float, std::string>
```

But I want to take only the unique types, something like

```cpp
std::variant<int, double, long, float, std::string>
```

I am actually building a parser that parses code and makes AST. I am using `std::variant` for storing node type and variant with multiple same type causes error. I'm not sure if what I've asked is possible, please let me know.